# throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is the error coming what to do.I have created a socket.io chat application.

### This is a chat application using nodejs.socket.io and with package.json as -

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.3.2",
    "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "hbs": "~4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.8",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport.socketio": "^3.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.6",
    "socket.io": "^1.5.1",
    "twemoji": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.13",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "*",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

---

```
C:\Users\AAKASH\Desktop\Follower-Github\Chat-app-all-F-2\Babble-master\B
abble-master\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:82            
  if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires 
a clientID option'); }                                                  
                           ^                                            

TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option                    
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (C:\Users\AAKASH\Desktop\Follower-Github\
Chat-app-all-F-2\Babble-master\Babble-master\node_modules\passport-oauth
2\lib\strategy.js:82:34)                                                
    at new Strategy (C:\Users\AAKASH\Desktop\Follower-Github\Chat-app-al
l-F-2\Babble-master\Babble-master\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\str
ategy.js:54:18)                                                         
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AAKASH\Desktop\Follower-Github\Chat-
app-all-F-2\Babble-master\Babble-master\config\passport.js:11:14)       
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)                               
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)                 
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)                                   
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)                                 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)                          
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)                                
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)                               
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AAKASH\Desktop\Follower-Github\Chat-
app-all-F-2\Babble-master\Babble-master\routes\index.js:9:14)           
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)                               
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)                 
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)                                   
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)                                 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)                          
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)                                
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)                               
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AAKASH\Desktop\Follower-Github\Chat-
app-all-F-2\Babble-master\Babble-master\app.js:23:16)                   
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)                               
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)                 
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)                                   
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                
npm ERR! errno 1                                                        
npm ERR! babble@0.1.0 start: `node ./bin/www`                           
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                  
npm ERR!                                                                
npm ERR! Failed at the babble@0.1.0 start script.                       
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additi
onal logging output above.                                              

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                    
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AAKASH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-08T
03_18_29_207Z-debug.log
```

---

Below is of no use.......
This is the error coming what to do.I have created a socket.io chat application.
This is a chat application using nodejs.socket.io and with package.jsonThis is the error coming what to do.I have created a socket.io chat application.
This is a chat application using nodejs.socket.io and with package.jsonThis is the error coming what to do.I have created a socket.io chat application.
This is a chat application using nodejs.socket.io and with package.json

Answer (score 18):

Recently, I faced the same issue and later I realized that I forgot to require .env configuration.

Error

```
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
```

Fix

```
npm i dotenv
```

and then require it at the top of your file

```
require(dotenv).config()
```

The issue is caused because your server has no idea that it has to use the environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error yesterday. error was

```js
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
```

I renamed client id as `clientID` instead of `clientId`

```js
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,       // previously was           clientId
  clientSecret: FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL,
  profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
},
  UserControllers.facebookCallback,
));
```

Comment: Yes, my property ...I had clientId: 'keys.googleClientID' and I changed to `clientID:`

Answer (score 2):

I have had a kind of similar scenario with Passport for GoogleOAuth2 with Google. Precisely the same error which eventually turned out to be something trivial. Somewhere in my code, where the portion cliendID keys are inserted, (in my case it was under keys.js) instead of export**S** I had a typo - export.

```
module.exports = require('./something');
```

Fixing that solved the issue. Hope somebody may find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing had happened to me and  then I added

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

in the header and everything worked.

I read my clientID from .env file.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem. Then I save clientId and clientSecret in .env file

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

passport.js

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log(profile);
      done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);
```

user.js

```
router.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/article');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure that your app can properly read your "clientID" variable. Try to read your variable "clientID" printing the value to the console. In my case the result was:

```
console.log(`${clientID}`);
undefined
```

I forgot to include the module

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

So I was not reading the actual clientID value.
Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set up the environment variable properly in your main file.
Add this before including the passport.js file in your server or app.js file

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this error says, it cannot find the clientID value, which was expected to come from .env definitions.

Working with nodejs and using for equal often :  instead of = as expected in .env causes this issue as well.

So ...    clientID=12345.....  then was Ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies do not help.  You need to post your code where you create your Passport Facebook Strategy object.  (I would XXXX out your personal codes/keys/ClientId)

I had this error as well literally just now, which is why I am here on this question.  I solved mine, and it may help you to hear how my issue came up.

It is very bad practice to put security codes/keys/whatever in a source code repository exposed to the wild.  It is a good practice to keep a file with your codes, and include it with the build as a reference, and use the keys out of it, but not check it in to the repo, but instead manually copy it from development computer to computer.  In a much larger environment, you may just have it located on a common network drive instead.  Or much more likely have it on a source code repository not hosted in the wild.

In my case, I was hopping from my main dev computer, a laptop, to my much faster desktop.  I have not been on the desktop in months, and just did a plain check out then compile/run.  I got this error.  I had forgotten to copy over the key file to run dev.  (Interestingly, I could absolutely run a build and push to live server, since it runs on a prod key file that sits on the server.)

If this is not your specific situation, then you need to either post your code (feel free to PM me if you want) or look at your code on how you are enacting your FacebookStrategy and your problem lies there.  You are probably just forgetting to include your Facebook ClientID in the call.

Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `consumer` to `client`, solved the issue.

```
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
      },
      function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        authUser(profile, done)
      }
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might also occur if you are placing multiple strategies under the same file 'passport.js', try making a different file for different strategies, try this when everything else is fine and the code still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow:

1. Login to your Heroku account. Under the personal tab, click the current application you are working on.
2. Go to settings.
3. Select "Reveal Config vars".
4. Add all the key-value pairs as you entered for your local environment.
5. Save the values.
6. Redeploy your application.

After putting hours finally it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add new Config vars for GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET in Heroku or any other providers if you have not. I had this error too and realized I forgot to add new Config vars to Heroku.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your code along with your error, but as per the error message I am seeing it seems like your code can't properly access the `clientID`. If you are using storing your `clientID` in a `.env` file use the [`dotenv`](https://npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module and configure it in your file by module `require("dotenv").config()`. I hope this will solve your problem.

Another reason can be, maybe you are not passing it as a string. The `clientID` key in the options expects a string as it's value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue due to the fact that I set the key of the key-value pair of the environment variables in heroku as `env.process.VARIABLE_KEY` and not just as `VARIABLE_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error.

I fixed it by simply changing my ".env" file to the project path

Answer (score 0):

happened with me also, i had typo i spelled CLIENT as CLENT in env file, so make sure you dont have any typing mistakes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

It's due to `.env` file, I recently came across this issue and I was actually looking for the solution everywhere since I had required and installed `dotenv`, I still faced this issue:

> TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option.

later I laughed at myself for a silly mistake I made inside my `.env` file which was I had accidently used ':' instead of '='.

check around for typos

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced the same issue and later I realized that in this line of code

> require(dotenv).config()

`dotenv` should be inside quotes like this

> require('dotenv').config()

.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing had happened to me and then I `require(dotenv).config()`
Then, add the client ID and secret. The contents of .env should look as follows.

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=__INSERT_CLIENT_ID_HERE__
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=__INSERT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE__
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you created ".env" file in the main project file, not in the inside of another folder.

| Project name |
| --- |
| Client |
| Server |
| package.json |
| **.env** |

Answer (score 0):

just add path on your dotenv require

```
require('dotenv').config({path : 'vars/.env'});
```

Comment: Your proposed solution seems very similar to many of the other existing, older posts here. Please make more obvious what additional insight your post provides - or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem recently. In my case, I got this error because I imported the passport setup before import importing express in my entiry file.

```
const passport = require("passport")
const express = require("express")
```

Do this instead

```
const express = require("express")
const passport = require("passport")
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced these problems, and after searching, I figured them out. For the first one, install the dependency for the environment variables

Install dotenv

`npm install dotenv` and then import in the Passport.js file.

> TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option`. For the second one just correct the syntax.

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.ClientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.ClientSecret,
      callBack: "auth/google/callback",
      scope: ["profile", "email"],
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, callBack) {
      // This function will be called after the user authenticates with Google
      // You can use the profile information to create or update a user in your database
      callBack(null, profile);
    }
  )
);
```

> TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a verify callback

Answer (score 0):

My .env file was named 'config.env.' Even though I was requiring the file in my passport-config.js with the correct route, it wasn't able to access it properly. When I was putting the client_id and client_secret key without passing them from the .env file, it was working fine. So, I renamed my .env file to '.env.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).