# I tried to deploy my Express.js app on Heroku so many times and I get "Application error"

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, application-error

I wanna deploy my Expree.js "Blogging-website" project on Heroku, But after trying soo many times I'm getting "Application error" that  your app has been crashed "H10". This is package.json file. I followed all the steps , please let me know if I've missed anything :

```
{
  "name": "ejs-challenge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
 },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:soniiya/Blogging-final.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.6"
  },
```

And also added this in my app.js file:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I've created Procfile too "web: node app.js". Actually when I deployed the same app without User Authentication feature, it deployed successfully but when added authentication it's crashing now. I used MongoDB for database, If you have any suggestions then please let me know. What can cause "App crashed" on heroku?

```
This is the "heroku logs":

$ heroku logs --app agile-journey-27742
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to
 »   7.59.2.
2021-12-25T15:01:48.138120+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:01:48.138120+00:00 app[api]: Set DB_PATH config vars by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:01:48.343377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-25T15:01:51.169675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-12-25T15:01:52.431858+00:00 app[web.1]: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 15:01:52 GMT express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at app.js:50:9
2021-12-25T15:01:52.432471+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-12-25T15:01:52.432472+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-12-25T15:01:52.432472+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442695+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442712+00:00 app[web.1]: if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442713+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442713+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442713+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442714+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87:34)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442714+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442714+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:97:14)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442714+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442718+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442718+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442719+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442719+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
2021-12-25T15:01:52.442719+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2021-12-25T15:01:52.585001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-25T15:01:52.686499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-25T15:02:05.594774+00:00 app[api]: Set DB_ADMIN config vars by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:02:05.594774+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:02:06.819898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-25T15:02:09.868314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-12-25T15:02:11.032225+00:00 app[web.1]: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 15:02:11 GMT express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at app.js:50:9        
2021-12-25T15:02:11.032895+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-12-25T15:02:11.032896+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-12-25T15:02:11.032896+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042607+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042608+00:00 app[web.1]: if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042609+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042609+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042610+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042610+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87:34)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042610+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042611+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:97:14)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042611+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042611+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042612+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042612+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042612+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
2021-12-25T15:02:11.042613+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2021-12-25T15:02:11.173932+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-25T15:02:11.236915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-25T15:02:18.714430+00:00 app[api]: Set DB_PASS config vars by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:02:18.714430+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:02:18.957618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-25T15:02:21.915023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-12-25T15:02:23.655207+00:00 app[web.1]: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 15:02:23 GMT express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at app.js:50:9        
2021-12-25T15:02:23.656076+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-12-25T15:02:23.656077+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-12-25T15:02:23.656077+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667352+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667354+00:00 app[web.1]: if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667355+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667355+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667355+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667356+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87:34)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667356+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667356+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:97:14)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667357+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667357+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
2021-12-25T15:02:23.667359+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2021-12-25T15:02:24.059553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-25T15:02:24.113339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-25T15:04:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:04:55.732410+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:04:55.732410+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 28c347cb by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2021-12-25T15:04:55.964469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-25T15:04:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-25T15:04:58.661868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-12-25T15:04:59.859458+00:00 app[web.1]: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 15:04:59 GMT express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at app.js:27:9        
2021-12-25T15:04:59.860069+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-12-25T15:04:59.860070+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-12-25T15:04:59.860070+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869458+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869466+00:00 app[web.1]: if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869466+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869467+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869467+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:87:34)
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869467+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
2021-12-25T15:04:59.869468+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:66:14)
rror code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agile-journey-27742.herokuapp.com request_id=aa9d093d-d785-4933-9c55-b9ce42ed5075 fwd="110.227.56.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-25T15:05:06.063156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=agile-journey-27742.herokuapp.com request_id=231a0059-325c-4e81-b20d-20c70a8065d3 fwd="110.227.56.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Does this solve your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752930/throw-new-typeerroroauth2strategy-requires-a-clientid-option/55995377

Comment: yes but now Heroku showing "Internal server error", how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

### **1. Try to set up this type of directory Structure**

```
|__client/  THIS IS EVERYTHING FROM THE REACT SIDE 
    |__ node_modules/
        |__ tons of stuff...
    |__ public/
        |__ index.html
        |__ favicon.ico
        |__ etc.
    |__ src/
        |__ index.js
        |__ main/
            |__ App.js
            |__ etc.
|__ models/
    |__ user.js
    |__ todo.js
    |__ etc.
|__ node_modules/
    |__ stuff...
|__ routes
    |__ userRoutes.js
    |__ todoRoutes.js
    |__ etc.
|__ .gitignore
|__ package.json
|__ server.js
|__ etc.
```

### **2. Please Add this Middleware**

```
// ... Other imports
const path = require("path");

// Other app.use middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

// Right before your app.listen(), add this:
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(...);
```

### **3. Add a proxy to the client's `package.json` based on your deploy server**

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

So, your `package.json` file looks like...

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
}
```

### **4. Setting environment variables on the website:**

```
A. Open your app in Heroku
B. Go to "Settings"
C. Click "Reveal Config Vars"
D. Add a new variable and click "Add". Done!
E. Your port has to look like:- process.env.PORT || 8000
```

Your Port looks like this:-

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
.
.
.
app.listen(port);
```

### **5. Set up MongoDB Atlas IP access control**

Next, you'll need to whitelist your IP address so that you can access your cluster. Go to Network Access on the navigation menu, and Add IP Address. You can either Add Your Current IP Address or **Allow Access from Anywhere**. **Confirm** your choice.

For any projects deployed through Heroku, you'll have to select Allow Access from Anywhere. This is because Heroku uses Dynamic IPs. While this isn't the most secure option, it is fine for now.

### **6. Add this scripts `start` `heroku-postbuild` and `engines`**

After all this, your server's `package.json` should look something like this:
In the terminal, type `node -v`. It should spit out the version of Node.js you're using. add this version in the `"engines": "14.17.5"`

```
{
    "name": "mern-to-heroku",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "server.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "mongoose": "^4.13.6",
        "morgan": "^1.9.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "14.17.5"
    }
}
```

## You should now be all set up to deploy your site through Heroku!

Comment: THANK YOU so much for all this info but I didn't use react.js in my app. This is Node.js and Express.js based app. So is this the solution for my app too (Node.js)?

Comment: [@SoniyaJaiswal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17281395/soniya-jaiswal) Then you have to take care of port which is use as `process.env.PORT` and also add all env variables in Reveal Config Vars on heroku

Comment: One more thing in root have to add `Procfile` ->  in this file `web: node app.js`

Comment: and yes add `"engines": {
    "node": "16.13.1"
  },` in `package.json` file simply you can find your node version with `node --version` in terminal

Comment: yes I did all that steps but now I'm getting "Internal server error" status=500. Can you tell me what can cause that problem? And also in some routes my css files and ejs templates are not loading , I really don't know why??

Comment: Ok Follow my next answer for css and js files and for ejs you have to set up middleware in app.js file

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your app can't find the Google Client ID.

It seems like you haven't configured your .env variables properly in Heroku. The solution is really simple.

DOTENV Approach
If you've defined your `.env` in this manner,

```
MONGO_URL="xxx.....xxx"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="xx......xxx"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="xxx.....xxx"
```

and in your passport-setup and db-setup you are using dotenv as,

```
require('dotenv').config();
.
.
.
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy
  (
    {
      clientID : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL : '/auth/google/callback'
    },
.
.
.
```

then, you must have declared a `.env` file in your project's root directory on your computer.

Your .gitignore file might have `.env` mentioned, as this is the standard way of doing it (You don't push env variables to public/team repositories).

The reason it works on your computer is that the app has the context of the environment variables. In Heroku since the `.env` file isn't present, the app doesn't know where to find them.

All you have to do is add your environment variables to Heroku. Just go to settings in Heroku Dashboard, go to the Config variables menu.

### Add your env variables in the format

### Restart the dyno.

This would solve your issue.

Comment: yess I did that but then I got "internal server error" , I even replaced redirect_uri in google credentials with heroku app name in which I tried to deploy but did no t work. So what's the solution?

Comment: And also in some routes my css files and ejs templates are not loading , I really don't know why?? It was working fine before but suddenly it's stopped working. Please help if you know.

Answer (score 0):

### **1. Add this middleware in the `app.js`**

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

### **2. Folder Structure**

```
|__public/   
    |__ css/
        |__ css files...
    |__ js/
        |__ js files...
```

**3. Import this way**

Now you set the path to the public directory you have to give the path public folder when you import

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

<script src="/js/main.js" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
```

## **You should now be all set up to access CSS files**